# MegaRAID SAS 2108 - Can I use different drives for the same array

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid5, megaraid

I know you can in general use different drive manufactures and size in general but does anyone know if the MegaRAID SAS 2108 card will let me do RAID 5 with multiple drives that are not the same in exact size/make/model?

As in, will it allow via the bios interface (Asking before buying additional drives)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but the array total size size will be dependant on the smallest disk. I mean - the size delta from smallest disk to biggest will be unused on all bigger drives.

Same restriction applies to replacing failed disks: you can replace smaller disk with bigger one, but not vice-versa (for obvious reasons).

Actually, I've never saw an array model that would require some vendor locking. May be some Sun/Oracle ones... All the LSI(or Avago if you want)/Adaptec and even PMC-Sierra SmartArray were accepting so-called *"disks from nearest computer parts market"*.